# Change class on date

Tags: javascript, class, date

Absolute scripting noob here, but i've got a problem that's been bugging me for 3 day's straight now.

I'm trying to create a script that will work like an advent calendar.

So:
01 dec 2014 door one opens,
02 dec 2014 door two opens (door one stay's open)
ect...

Now i might have gotten this totally wrong but what i've got at the moment is :

```js
$(function(){
    // Event handler to close the current popup when clicking on widgets with the "close_when_clicked" extra css class
    $('body').on('click', '.boxy-content.close_when_clicked', function(e){
        if (!$(e.target).is('a')){
            e.preventDefault();
            var boxy = Boxy.get(this);
            boxy.hideAndUnload();        
        }
    });

    var i, 
        current_day, 
        day, 
        startDate;
    var $cal = $('.calendar'), 
        $prizes = $('.prizes > *'),
        $lockedMsg = $('.locked_msg');
    var now = new Date(), 
        totalDays = $prizes.length;

    // change # of days displayed
    $('span.total_days').text(totalDays);

    // check for date override
    var timenow_re = window.location.href.match(/timenow=([\w%]+)/);
    if (timenow_re) {
        var parsed = Date.parse(decodeURIComponent(timenow_re[1]));
        if (parsed) {
            now = new Date(parsed);
        }
    }
    var nowDate = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());

    startDate = new Date(startYear, startMonth - 1, startDay);
    secsPerDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    currentDay = Math.floor( (nowDate - startDate + 1) / secsPerDay ) + 1;

    // setup links for each day
    for (i=1; i<=totalDays; i++) {
        $cal.append('<a class="day' + ((i > currentDay) ? " locked" : " unlocked") + '" href="#" data-day="' + i + '">' + i + '</a>');
    }

    // unlocked click handler
    $('.calendar .unlocked').attr('target', '').click(function(event) {
        var day = $(event.target).data('day');
        var prize = $prizes.get(day-1);
        if (prize) {
            var config = SST.widget_config(prize);
            SST.widget_popup(config, this);
        }
        else {
            ss_alert('There is no popup configured for Day ' + day + '. Add a Rich Text, Image, Promotion or Custom Form widget configured to display as a popup, then add it to the Calendar Settings.');
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    // locked click handler
    $('.calendar .locked').attr('target', '').click(function(event) {
        var config = SST.widget_config($lockedMsg.get(0));
        SST.widget_popup(config, this);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

```html
    <a class="day unlocked" href="#" data-day="1" target="">1</a>
    <a class="day unlocked" href="#" data-day="2" target="">2</a>
    <a class="day unlocked" href="#" data-day="3" target="">3</a>
    <a class="day unlocked" href="#" data-day="4" target="">4</a>
    <a class="day unlocked" href="#" data-day="5" target="">5</a>
    <a class="day unlocked" href="#" data-day="6" target="">6</a>
    <a class="day unlocked" href="#" data-day="7" target="">7</a>
    <a class="day unlocked" href="#" data-day="8" target="">8</a>
    <a class="day unlocked" href="#" data-day="9" target="">9</a>
    <a class="day unlocked" href="#" data-day="10" target="">10</a>
    <a class="day unlocked" href="#" data-day="11" target="">11</a>
    <a class="day unlocked" href="#" data-day="12" target="">12</a>
    <a class="day unlocked" href="#" data-day="13" target="">13</a>
    <a class="day unlocked" href="#" data-day="14" target="">14</a>
    <a class="day unlocked" href="#" data-day="15" target="">15</a>
    <a class="day unlocked" href="#" data-day="16" target="">16</a>
    <a class="day unlocked" href="#" data-day="17" target="">17</a>
    <a class="day unlocked" href="#" data-day="18" target="">18</a>
    <a class="day locked" href="#" data-day="19" target="">19</a>
    <a class="day locked" href="#" data-day="20" target="">20</a>
    <a class="day locked" href="#" data-day="21" target="">21</a>
    <a class="day locked" href="#" data-day="22" target="">22</a>
    <a class="day locked" href="#" data-day="23" target="">23</a>
    <a class="day locked" href="#" data-day="24" target="">24</a>
</div>
```

The Class of the HTML should change to "Day locked" when the date is before the 1st of december.
then on the 1st the code should change the class of date-dat="1" to "Day unlocked'  and so on.

Could anyone give me a few pointers how i can change the class on a specific date? ( and not all one once, but one day at a time? )

Thanks in advance !!

edit: I've also tried some PHP, but

```
<a class="day <?php if(date('z') == 304 ) echo 'unlocked' ?> href="#" data-day="1" target="" ">1</a>
```

didnt seem to work....

Comment: Javascript and Java are very different - I've modified your tags appropriately.

Comment: I've also tried some PHP, but
<a class="day <?php if(date('z') == 304 ) echo 'unlocked' ?> href="#" data-day="1" target="" ">1</a>

didnt seem to work....